# Position of memory in a two dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, location

In C, a position a[i] in an array is equal to *(a+i). However, for a two dimensional array a[i][j], what would be the equivalent pointer? I arrived at 
*(a + ((i*(size of the second array) + j)), but this doesn't seem like a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

Position `a[i]` is `*(a+i)`

Position `a[i][j]` is `*(*(a + i) + j)`

Remember that a 2 dimensional array is an array of arrays. Therefore `*a+0` points to the first array, `*a+1` points to the second array, and so on.

To simplify...

`*(*a+1) = *(*(a + 0) + 1 ) =  *(a[0] + 1) = a[0][1]`

Comment: Worth noting, even if the implementation is an array of pointers (i.e. a faux 2D array) the math *still* works. Only the numbers being crunched are altered, but the results are still correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i][j] is *(a[i] + j) or  *(*(a + i) + j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes :

```
*(a + ((i(size of the second array) + j))
```

are for 2D vector, if you allocate 2D array in continous memory you can index like in following example:

```
float *I = (float*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(float));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(i==j) I[i*n+i]=1.0;
            else I[i*n+j]=0.0;
}
}
```

It's identity matrix in continous memory block.